# How can i read data from .txt file using c#?

Tags: c#, delimiter

I want to read data from specific path but i the program read the first line only.
my program gets data from user and save it int .txt file then i want to display all contents in between the delimiters.

*input*

```
1@aaa@bbbb@2@c@f@3@r@t
```

*output*

```
Id:1
Name:aaa
Address:bbbb

Id:2
Name:c
Address:f

Id:3
Name:r
Address:t
```

here is my code:
**main**

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\New folder\a ", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sd = new StreamReader(fs);
string s;
while (true)
{                            
    s = sd.ReadLine();
    field = s.Split(std.delimiter);
    std.ID = field[0];
    std.Name = field[1];
    std.Address = field[2];
    std.Display_data();
    sd.Close();
    fs.Close();
    break;
}
```

**class**

```
public void Display_data()
{
     Console.WriteLine(ID);
     Console.WriteLine(Name);
     Console.WriteLine(Address);    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i edited it, please read it again.

Comment: `break` exists the while-loop immediately after the first execution. Remove it and replace the loop condition with an appropriate test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove

```
break;
```

Edit while condition and move

```
sd.Close();
fs.Close();
```

out of the while cycle.
So your while cycle should look like this

```
while (!sd.EndOfStream)
{                            
    s = sd.ReadLine();
    field = s.Split(std.delimiter);
    std.ID = field[0];
    std.Name = field[1];
    std.Address = field[2];
    std.Display_data();
}
sd.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: `sd.RreadLine()` will throw `ObjectDisposedException` after `sd.Close()`. You need to move both of those `.Close()` calls outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: i'll edit it right now

Answer (score 0):

Read line,split using '@' and then read 3 line items and print out the lineitems.

```
using(StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(@"E:\Newfolder\a\test.txt"))
{
    string [] sLineItems = oReader.ReadLine().Split('@');

    for(int i = 0;i < sLineItems.Length; i = i+3)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Id:{0}",sLineItems[i]);
          Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}",sLineItems[i+1]);
          Console.WriteLine("Address:{0}",sLineItems[i+2]);
    }
}
```